# Normal RGB to Apple RGB in Swift

Tags: swift, colors

So, I've been experimenting with some color stuff in Swift and I encountered a problem. I realized that I have no idea how to convert between normal RGB (values between 0 and 255) and Apple's RGB (values between 0 and 1). Is there some Swift function to do this, or do I just use a proportion?

Also, now this is a bonus: Does anybody know why Apple uses RGB values between 0 and 1 as opposed to 0 and 255 in the first place? If the answer to this question is not short, then please tell me in the comments and I'll ask it separately.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just take your rgb values and divide them by 255

example:

```
let thisColor = UIColor(red: 10/255.0, green: 20/255.0, blue: 30/255.0, alpha: 40/255.0)
```